# Kafka streams aggregation duplication

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There is a Topology:

```
.mapValues((key, messages) -> remoteService.sendMessages(messages))
.flatMapValues(results -> results)
.map((key, result) -> KeyValue.pair(getAggregationKey(result), getAggregationResult(systemClock, result)))
.groupByKey(Grouped.with(createJsonSerde(AggregationKey.class), createJsonSerde(AggregationResult.class)))
.windowedBy(timeWindows)
.reduce((aggregatedResult, v) -> {
    int count = aggregatedResult.getCount();
    return aggregatedResult.toBuilder().count(count + 1).build();
})
.suppress(untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
```

TimeWindows:

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(60);    
TimeWindows timeWindows = TimeWindows.of(duration).grace(Duration.ZERO);
```

My assumption is that aggregation results has to be sent to sink topic every 60 seconds or so but I noticed sometimes it sends duplicates(numbers are not precise): first event was sent at 50th second with counter 1000 and then at 58th second event with the same key was sent with counter 1050. It happens not every minute but quite frequently. Why could this happen?

What I also noticed is that the second event always has timestamp less than first one but larger offset. The same is for internal reduce topic.

Comment: I assume you are hitting: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7895

Comment: Thanks. We already implemented aggregation using transformer but if there will be a chance I will test it using Kafka streams v2.2.0 to be sure issue is not reproduced anymore